# Kentico Import Tool inconsistent/buggy when updating documents

Tags: import, kentico

I've had a number of problems using the provided Kentico Import Toolkit, namely when using the "Import new and overwrite existing pages" option to update my existing/already imported pages. I'm using a custom SQL query to import and have had a profile saved for each import I've needed (client has article based site so a few tables of similar information) to try and keep each as consistent as possible between imports.

Here's the problems I've encountered thus far (in no particular order):

- the tool tries to guess which fields from the query correlates to the fields of the page type in Kentico for you, which is a nice idea, but seems poorly implemented. If I'm not very careful and reload the profiles every time I import I've had instances where fields changed inexplicably when testing imports because the tool thought it knew which field I wanted

  - this is more the problem when importing/reimporting multiple times in a session and choosing to go back and load the same profile (without reloading)
- the NodeAlias field is only seemingly required on update/reimport rather than on initial import. I'm sure there's an internal cleaning of the document's title to generate a NodeAlias and this is generated fine when importing documents while NOT providing the NodeAlias. After importing the items initially and wishing to update however the NodeAlias is seemingly required as you'll get errors with text asking it be included. This implies to me that there's matching of the NodeAlias along with the given ID field, which should be fine in theory but isn't specifically mentioned anywhere in the tool as best I can tell.
- I've had instances where reimporting items will change/strip their NodeAliasPath. I've gotten around this by specifically setting the NodeAliasPath (which only shows after selecting "Show Advanced Columns") but like NodeAlias path before it, I'd think the tool should be smart enough to know to keep the path if not specifically given for updated items.
- it seems very odd that in order to match on ID for previous items you have to provide the name of the new column instead of the old one. My example: client was using just a field named 'id' and the new one is 'OriginalID' to clearly differentiate it from the Kentico derived ID fields. To match the items I have to use 'OriginalID' rather than 'id'

A couple of notes/niceties or potential updates along with the above:

- it would be nice if there were some way to select if the page should
  be published or not through a single query. Currently having the
  "Automatically publish pages under workflow" toggle checked seems to always publish
  the items. I have an instance where the client has old documents in
  the provided DB dump that they don't want visible on the site but
  want preserved in the DB if they change their mind later. Currently I
  have to perform 2 imports, 1 for the unpublished and a second for the
  published items, to accommodate this, which is quite cumbersome

I'll likely edit/add to this as I get responses. This isn't really a specific problem (as I managed a workaround to the NodeAliasPath stripping problem, which inspired this post initially) but more just me asking if these are bugs,if I'm not using the software as intended, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You've stated all the problems you're having/experiencing and possibilities why they are happening but didn't ask a particular question.  If you suspect they are bugs, then I'd go to directly to [Kentico Support](https://devnet.kentico.com/support) and report the issues there since these are things that have been part of the KIT for as long as I have worked with it.

Comment: I had an initial problem of being unable to preserve the NodeAliasPath with subsequent imports/updates as stated but managed a workaround. In hindsight this post likely isn't really that helpful but at least for that particular question I wasn't providing a NodeAliasPath or NodeAlias to the tool directly and thus they're getting autogenerated as the items are imported. I'd question why either is needed then for already existing items as long as a relevant id is given for matching purposes.